# Delete topic using EmbeddedKafkaBroker

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, embedded-kafka

I wrote a test class in which I'would test topic deletion

I found for `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` this method

```
embeddedKafkaBroker.addTopics("new-topic");
```

that make me able to create a new topic, but I can't find anything to delete a topic.

So, how can I test topic deletion?

Answer (score 1):

See this one:

```
/**
 * Create an {@link AdminClient}; invoke the callback and reliably close the admin.
 * @param callback the callback.
 */
public void doWithAdmin(java.util.function.Consumer<AdminClient> callback) {
```

where you can use:

```
/**
 * This is a convenience method for {@link #deleteTopics(TopicCollection, DeleteTopicsOptions)}
 * with default options. See the overload for more details.
 * <p>
 * This operation is supported by brokers with version 0.10.1.0 or higher.
 *
 * @param topics The topic names to delete.
 * @return The DeleteTopicsResult.
 */
default DeleteTopicsResult deleteTopics(Collection<String> topics) {
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on Artem's answer, this can be a bit tricky because of the asynchronicity of the events involved.

<s>If the topic doesn't exist in the Kafka broker the `describeTopics` method in `KafkaAdminClient` throws an `UnknownTopicOrPartitionException` wrapped in an `ExecutionException`, so we can leverage that to check the topic's existence and wait for its creation or deletion.</s>

EDIT: While the above strategy does work, the proper way to do this is to just wait for the future to complete, for example with `admin.deleteTopics(List.of(topicName)).all().get()`

But since the Embedded broker is not aware that the topic has been deleted, the `embeddedKafkaBroker.getTopics()` result doesn't get updated, so in order to find out if the topic has actually been deleted we need to use the  `admin.describeTopics(List.of(topicName)).all().get()` method instead.

Comment: Thanks, Tomaz! Tell me, please, why don't you use that `DeleteTopicsResult.all().get()` instead?

Comment: You're right, thanks. In my first attempt at this I relied on `embeddedKafkaBroker.getTopics()`, and even though I waited for the deletion future to complete, the topic was never removed, so I thought it didn't work as expected. That led me to this different path. Now using the describeTopics instead I see waiting for the Future works. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Running admin.deleteTopics(admin.listTopics().names().get()).all().get() (so delete all known topics) before each test, after a while seems to cause: Expected 3 but got 0 partitions
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 3 but got 0 partitions
 at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils.waitForSingleContainerAssignment(ContainerTestUtils.java:115)

any idea why? The proposed solution is to use @DirtiesContext, but this makes tests slower.